# Versioning Objects in a DB and Replaying Transactions with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Ok, I have the following problem.

I'd like to use SQLAlchemy to version objects in my DB. I understand how to do this by, eg, [creating my own mixin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/_modules/examples/versioned_rows/versioned_rows.html). Changes will include inserts and updates, but not schema changes.

I'd also like to promote my DB to a QA/Production server by replaying those changes, a la a git merge.

The easiest way to do this is to add a column to the objects in the DB with a version number/timestamp, and write a SELECT MAX type query. But I was talking to a dev friend, and Ruby seems to have something (ActiveRecord?) that generates update scripts that you can keep in git. Then promoting the DB is just a matter of running those scripts.

I found [SQLAlchemy Migrate](http://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/versioning.html), which versions the *schema* (which I don't expect to change). But it's not clear that that versions the *data* (unless I'm missing something).

At any rate, this seems like a problem people have a good way of solving, any hints?

(I'm not wedded to any particular technology, but we have a good understanding of Python, and it'd have to be pretty compelling to do this using something else. I chose SQLAlchemy in the example above because it's the Python ORM with which I am most familiar.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid large amount of copy/paste, please see the following:

- [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a lightweight database migration tool for usage with the SQLAlchemy Database Toolkit for Python. *(Written by the author of SQLAlchemy)*
- and following stackoverflow questions related to it:

  - [Creating seed data in a flask-migrate or alembic migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334604/creating-seed-data-in-a-flask-migrate-or-alembic-migration)
  - [How do I execute inserts and updates in an Alembic upgrade script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612395/how-do-i-execute-inserts-and-updates-in-an-alembic-upgrade-script)
  - where your implementation would most probably use also [`bulk_insert()`](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.bulk_insert) method

This might not be as automated as you wish it to be, but it will support migration of static data.