# How do I seed a flask sql-alchemy database

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I am new at python, I just learnt how to create an api using flask restless and flask sql-alchemy. I however would like to seed the database with random values. How do I achieve this? Please help. 
Here is the api code...

```
import flask
import flask.ext.sqlalchemy
import flask.ext.restless
import datetime

DATABASE = 'sqlite:///tmp/test.db'

#Create the Flask application and the FLask-SQLALchemy object
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config ['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =  DATABASE
db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)

#create Flask-SQLAlchemy models
class TodoItem(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    todo = db.Column(db.Unicode)
    priority = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    due_date = db.Column(db.Date)

#Create database tables
db.create_all()

#Create Flask restless api manager
manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db = db)

#Create api end points
manager.create_api(TodoItem, methods = ['GET','POST','DELETE','PUT'], results_per_page = 20)

#Start flask loop
app.run()
```

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334604/creating-seed-data-in-a-flask-migrate-or-alembic-migration

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar question and did some research, found something that worked.

The pattern I am seeing is based on registering a [Flask CLI custom command](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#custom-commands), something like: `flask seed`.

This would look like this given your example. First, import the following into your api code file (let's say you have it named `server.py`):

```
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
```

(I see you do `import flask` but I would just add you should change these to `from flask import what_you_need`)

Next, create a function that does the seeding for your project:

```
@with_appcontext
def seed():
   """Seed the database."""
   todo1 = TodoItem(...).save()
   todo2 = TodoItem(...).save()
   todo3 = TodoItem(...).save()
```

Finally, register these command with your flask application:

```
def register_commands(app):
    """Register CLI commands."""
    app.cli.add_command(seed)
```

After you've configured you're application, make sure you call `register_commands` to register the commands:

```
register_commands(app)
```

At this point, you should be able to run: `flask seed`. You can add more functions (maybe a `flask reset`) using the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

From another newbie, the [forgerypy](https://tomekwojcik.github.io/ForgeryPy/index.html) and forgerypy3 libraries are available for this purpose (though they look like they haven't been touched in a bit).

A simple example of how to use them by adding them to your model:

```
class TodoItem(db.Model):

    ....

    @staticmethod
    def generate_fake_data(records=10):
        import forgery_py
        from random import randint
        for record in records:
            todo = TodoItem(todo=forgery_py.lorem_ipsum.word(),
                            due_date=forgery_py.date.date(),
                            priority=randint(1,4))
            db.session.add(todo)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
```

You would then call the generate_fake_data method in a shell session.

And Miguel Grinberg's Flask Web Development (the O'Reilly book, not blog) chapter 11 is a good resource for this.

Comment: Pointers to a book don't really answer the question,

Comment: Yes, I agree. I would have added it as a comment but I don't have enough points (though I am allowed to comment on my own answer). Totally willing to remove it to conform with stack overflow's format if you advise. I was looking for the same thing, and only found this question.